# Informatica Coding to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, informatica

I am attempting to translate the following Informatica code to the equivalent SQL scripts. I am a little stuck as I am not familiar with Informatica and would appreciate any assistance.

The original informatica code reads as follows:

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(COV_REINS_CONCAT_BK,11, INSTR(COV_REINS_CONCAT_BK, '|',1,3)-INSTR(COV_REINS_CONCAT_BK, '|',1,2)-1 ))) || 'C'
```

Comment: Informatica works with different databases, so that is already sql, probably Oracle looking at the concatenation operator ||

Comment: @Mihai: `||` is the operator for string concatenation defined by the SQL standard and is not specific to Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

```
select LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(COV_REINS_CONCAT_BK,11,INSTR(COV_REINS_CONCAT_BK,'|',1‌​,3)
-INSTR(COV_REINS_CONCAT_BK,'|',1,2)-1 )))||'C' from TABLE;
```

Above script will work fine in Oracle. Please replace table with your table name.

Answer (score 0):

It becomes increasingly difficult to port such expressions that make extensive use of **INSTR** function using the occurrence parameter.

Maybe it's easier to create in your MS-SQL database an INSTR equivalent function that supports the occurrence parameter. See how to create the dbo.INSTR function [here](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/functions/instr).
On this same site you can also see a [table](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/functions) with more function equivalences from Oracle to MS-SQL.

Then the expression from the comment becomes much easier to translate:

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(COV_REINS_CONCAT_BK,11,dbo.INSTR(COV_REINS_CONCAT_BK,'|',1‌​,3)
-dbo.INSTR(COV_REINS_CONCAT_BK,'|',1,2)-1 )))+'C'
```

Here SUBSTR became **SUBSTRING**, and INSTR became **dbo.INSTR** and concatenation || was changed to +.

Comment: Hi Cosmin, Thank you very much for your help yet again! I have been able to create the Function, and I am still awaiting access to execute the function--I will let you know when it works!

Answer (score 0):

The SUBSTR() and instr() functions are from the Informatica Transformation Language. IMHO it has its roots in function names from Oracle and MSSQL / Sybase function names. This is why it doesn't translate directly to either but is similar. The functions are very well documented in the online help. You'll need to review the switches in the INSTR() function for case sensitivity and the like to ensure their parallel can be written correctly in another tool. The numbers may translate to different things and in some of the Informatica functions the end arguments can be omitted such as, in the SUBSTR() function, meaning that the SUBSTR() will take effect from the numbered position to the end of the string regardless of length. The typing of the port in Informatica can affect the result too, although in this case, the combined function is performing a trim at the end.

Answer (score -1):

SUBSTR() and INSTR() functions are not MS SQL Server functions.  I'm guessing the code snippet is Oracle's PL/SQL.  Try resources such as http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_news/2005_12_16_sql_syntax_differences.htm

Comment: Can anyone enlighten me as to what was particularly bad about this response as to warrant a downvote?  The OP asked for 'any assistance' and I always figure you're better off pointing someone in the right direction rather than just doing all the work for them.